# My SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces is not working

Tags: c++, device, hid, wdk

I am interested to find out if I am doing this right:

```
//DeviceManager.h
#include <windows.h>
//#include <hidsdi.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <devpkey.h>

extern "C"{
    #include <hidsdi.h>
}

//#pragma comment (lib, "setupapi.lib")

class DeviceManager
{
public:
    DeviceManager();
    ~DeviceManager();

    void ListAllDevices();
    void GetDevice(std::string vid, std::string pid);

    HANDLE PSMove;
    byte reportBuffer;
private:
    HDEVINFO deviceInfoSet;             //A list of all the devices
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData;     //A device from deviceInfoSet

    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetailedData;

};

//DeviceManager.cpp
#include"DeviceManager.h"

DeviceManager::DeviceManager()
{
    deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, TEXT("USB"), NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_ALLCLASSES); //Gets all Devices
}

DeviceManager::~DeviceManager()
{
}

void DeviceManager::ListAllDevices()
{
    DWORD deviceIndex = 0;

    deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

    while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoSet, deviceIndex, &deviceInfoData))
    {
        deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

        ULONG tcharSize;
        CM_Get_Device_ID_Size(&tcharSize, deviceInfoData.DevInst, 0);
        TCHAR* deviceIDBuffer = new TCHAR[tcharSize];   //the device ID will be stored in this array, so the tcharSize needs to be big enough to hold all the info.
                                                        //Or we can use MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN, which is 200

        CM_Get_Device_ID(deviceInfoData.DevInst, deviceIDBuffer, MAX_PATH, 0); //gets the devices ID - a long string that looks like a file path.

        /*
        //SetupDiGetDevicePropertyKeys(deviceInfoSet, &deviceInfoData, &devicePropertyKey, NULL, 0, 0);
        if( deviceIDBuffer[8]=='8' && deviceIDBuffer[9]=='8' && deviceIDBuffer[10]=='8' && deviceIDBuffer[11]=='8' && //VID
            deviceIDBuffer[17]=='0' && deviceIDBuffer[18]=='3' && deviceIDBuffer[19]=='0' && deviceIDBuffer[20]=='8') //PID
        {
            std::cout << deviceIDBuffer << "\t<-- Playstation Move" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << deviceIDBuffer << std::endl;
        }*/

        std::cout << deviceIDBuffer << std::endl;

        deviceIndex++;
    }
}

void DeviceManager::GetDevice(std::string vid, std::string pid)
{

    DWORD deviceIndex = 0;
    deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

    while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoSet, deviceIndex, &deviceInfoData))
    {
        deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

        ULONG IDSize;
        CM_Get_Device_ID_Size(&IDSize, deviceInfoData.DevInst, 0);

        TCHAR* deviceID = new TCHAR[IDSize];

        CM_Get_Device_ID(deviceInfoData.DevInst, deviceID, MAX_PATH, 0);

        if( deviceID[8]==vid.at(0) && deviceID[9]==vid.at(1) && deviceID[10]==vid.at(2) && deviceID[11]==vid.at(3) && //VID
            deviceID[17]==pid.at(0) && deviceID[18]==pid.at(1) && deviceID[19]==pid.at(2) && deviceID[20]==pid.at(3)) //PID
        {
            //DWORD requiredBufferSize;
            //SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoSet, &deviceInterfaceData, NULL, 0, &requiredBufferSize, 


            HDEVINFO deviceInterfaceSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&deviceInfoData.ClassGuid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);

            DWORD deviceInterfaceIndex = 0;
            deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInterfaceData);
            while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInterfaceSet, NULL, &deviceInterfaceData.InterfaceClassGuid, deviceInterfaceIndex, &deviceInterfaceData))
            {
                deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInterfaceData);
                std::cout << deviceInterfaceIndex << std::endl;

                deviceInterfaceIndex++;
            }

            //std::cout << deviceInterfaceData.cbSize << std::endl;

            break;
        }

        deviceIndex++;
    }
}
```

My SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces (in the GetDevice() function) is not doing anything. It is not even entering the while loop. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

### Edit

I've just called the GetLastError() function and it has returned a 259 - ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS. Is it even possible for a device to contain no interfaces?

Comment: `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` is returning false then. Look at the documentation to determine why this might be and then use your debugger. If you still can't figure it out then ask a more specific question about where you got stuck then.

Comment: Then May I please ask if the deviceInfoData.ClassGuid been passed correct? I mean, I am suppost to be passing that guid to get the deviceInterfaceSet? Or am I suppost to pass it a different GUID?

Comment: If you never enter the while loop then you never get to that line of code which means you are using the `deviceInfoSet` assigned in the constructor. Hint: Use `FormatMessage` with `GetLastError` to determine specifically what went wrong after the call to `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` It could simply be that there are no present active USB devices available on the system.

Comment: have compiled & run your code without a hitch; eg: `DeviceManager::ListAllDevices` returns for me: `003796F8 00379800` ~i think you have no devices ;) ~best to bung in a check for the return value when you call `SetupDiGetClassDevs`

Comment: @violet313 I've created a DeviceManager object and called the ListAllDevices function and it displayed a list of USB devices' IDs :S...

Comment: hmm, well fwiw i was also making it inside the `while` of your `DeviceManager::GetDevice` ~out of interest, what do you think the difference in the the two respective calls to `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` may be? are your calling these methods on the same instance? ~is some *other* code *doing something* to your `deviceInfoSet` value?

Comment: @violet313 I am not even using deviceInfoSet for that function :S. I have created another HDEVINFO called deviceInterfaceSet in the GetDevice function. SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo enumerates the devices, SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces enumerates the interfaces of a device. Also, there are no other code doing something to my deviceInfoSet. DeviceManager.h, DeviceManager.cpp and Mainframe.cpp is the only files I have, but Mainframe.cpp only contains my int main function that calls GetDevice().

Comment: ah yes. wrong while ~i is eejit lol...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a go with this.

I have tried to hack your original code about as little as possible; the following codes (for me at least) get through to the inner `while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces..)`:

```
void DeviceManager::GetDeviceUSB(std::string vid, std::string pid)
{
    DWORD deviceIndex = 0;
    deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

    //buried somewhere deep in the ddk
    static GUID GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB={ 0xf18a0e88, 0xc30c, 0x11d0, {0x88, 0x15, 0x00, 0xa0, 0xc9, 0x06, 0xbe, 0xd8} };
    static GUID GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE ={ 0xA5DCBF10L, 0x6530, 0x11D2, { 0x90, 0x1F, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xB9, 0x51, 0xED } };
    static GUID GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HOST_CONTROLLER={ 0x3abf6f2d, 0x71c4, 0x462a, {0x8a, 0x92, 0x1e, 0x68, 0x61, 0xe6, 0xaf, 0x27}};

    //get usb device interfaces
    HDEVINFO deviceInterfaceSet=SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);


    while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInterfaceSet, deviceIndex, &deviceInfoData))
    {
        deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInfoData);

        ULONG IDSize;
        CM_Get_Device_ID_Size(&IDSize, deviceInfoData.DevInst, 0);

        TCHAR* deviceID = new TCHAR[IDSize];

        CM_Get_Device_ID(deviceInfoData.DevInst, deviceID, MAX_PATH, 0);

        if( deviceID[8]==vid.at(0) && deviceID[9]==vid.at(1) && deviceID[10]==vid.at(2) && deviceID[11]==vid.at(3) && //VID
            deviceID[17]==pid.at(0) && deviceID[18]==pid.at(1) && deviceID[19]==pid.at(2) && deviceID[20]==pid.at(3)) //PID
        {
            DWORD deviceInterfaceIndex = 0;
            deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInterfaceData);

            while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInterfaceSet, &deviceInfoData, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, deviceInterfaceIndex, &deviceInterfaceData))
            {
                deviceInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(deviceInterfaceData);
                std::cout << deviceInterfaceIndex << std::endl;

                //get some more details etc
                //DWORD requiredBufferSize;
                //SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInterfaceSet, &deviceInterfaceData, NULL, 0, &requiredBufferSize, 

                deviceInterfaceIndex++;
            }
        }

        deviceIndex++;
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this method picks up the same devices as with your OP constructor call *(NB: I included some other useful interface guids)*:

```
deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, TEXT("USB"), NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_ALLCLASSES); //Gets all Devices
```

But I am doing this to get the device *interfaces*:

```
// /coughs/ you might want to put back the DIGCF_PRESENT flag I removed for testing
HDEVINFO deviceInterfaceSet=SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
```

I also pass the `deviceInfoData` to `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` since according to the documentation:

> A pointer to an SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure that specifies a device
>   information element in DeviceInfoSet. This parameter is optional and
>   can be NULL. If this parameter is specified,
>   SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces constrains the enumeration to the
>   interfaces that are supported by the specified device. If this
>   parameter is NULL, repeated calls to SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces
>   return information about the interfaces that are associated with all
>   the device information elements in DeviceInfoSet. This pointer is
>   typically returned by SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo.

### Edit

Additional note as requested. Your USB device has an associated *setup* class **and** *interface* class(es):

From the [device setup classes documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> *The device setup class defines the class installer and class co-installers that are involved in installing the device*

From the [device interface classes documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> *A device interface class is a way of exporting device and driver functionality to other system components, including other drivers, as
>   well as user-mode applications*

- [Also, see this handy comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Also, this related doc is useful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So:

```
deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, TEXT("USB"), NULL,DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
```

This is retrieving all *setup* class information sets and filtering on "USB"

You *could* do this:

```
deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_ALLCLASSES|DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);`
```

This retrieves class information sets for devices that support a *device interface* of *any* class. (Applying an emumerator ID s/a "USB" seems to have no affect).

Crucially however: *`The function adds to the device information set a device information element that represents such a device and then adds to the device information element a device interface list that contains all the device interfaces that the device supports.`*

(***And note:*** `SP_DEVINFO_DATA.ClassGuid` is *always* the GUID of the device's *setup* class)

As far as I know, you then still need to provide an *`InterfaceClassGuid`* when invoking `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces()`. To be honest, I don't really understand why this would be necessary if the caller is providing the optional *`DeviceInfoData`* but since it's all closed source, how would I know?  :)

And here is [info regarding GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

<sub>Disclaimer: I do not work for M$; do treat the above information with suspicion, and of course do your own research.</sub>

Comment: that works and it is exactly what I need! Thanks alot :D. If you don't mind, can I also ask you to explain a bit more about the GUID that you've declared at the top?? Why do we need them when I've used TEXT("USB")? What is the difference? Or can you atleast provide me a link where I can look up more info about the GUIDs that you've declared?? Thanks :D

Comment: noP, see revised answer,, btw lol, i am *not an [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) XD

Comment: I wish I could up vote this more than once. You must have put a lot of effort into this answer. I have one more piece of information to add, having thrashed about for over a day looking for it: If your device is a WinUSB device, then the GUID you pass to `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces()` will be the "DeviceInterfaceGUIDs" value from the registry/inf file. I very much doubt this is documented anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

The problem starts with how SetupDiGetClassDevs is called.

If you are looking to get a device path, use
SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE ,,,)

SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces fails with error 259 if SetupDiGetClassDevs is given the wrong GUID in 
ClassGuid which MS Help says is 
*A pointer to the GUID for a device setup class or a device interface class.*

Include file devguid.h contains a set of GUID_DEVCLASS values. These are **NOT** the same as GUID_DEVINTERFACE_* values which are the one you need.

Use #include <uuids.h> which includes ksuuids.h  where you'll find GUID_DEVINTERFACE_* values.

There's a more detailed explanation on my website, with some source code that should help in correctly enumerating USB devices.

See http://pixcl.com/SetupDiEnumInterfaces_Fail.htm