# Use Windows BLE using c++

Tags: c++, winapi, com, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to use the BLE feature of the winodws 10 laptop. I've first used the c# based examples available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) . I can use the laptop as a BLE peripheral mode as well as the server mode. Now I'd like to implement the same feature in c++. I've found that the API that I should use to implement this is found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450825(v=vs.85).aspx).

I followed [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bad452cb-4fc2-4a86-9b60-070b43577cc9/is-there-a-simple-example-desktop-programming-c-for-bluetooth-low-energy-devices?forum=wdk) example to implement an initial server mode in the windows 10 laptop computer. But I first need the peripheral mode and I tried to add the class ID of my BLE device found from the device manager.

[image]

But the `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` function fails with the error code 0x103 (No further information)

```
hDI = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&BluetoothInterfaceGUID, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT);
if (hDI == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return NULL;

did.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
dd.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

BOOL isComplete = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDI, NULL, &BluetoothInterfaceGUID, 0, &did);
```

Any idea why this call fails? Should I be using any other GUID instead of the class GUID?

Comment: i think you should look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587914/my-setupdienumdeviceinterfaces-is-not-working

Comment: Thanks, I can see that they have used the device GUID. But in my case I've used the class GUID. I'm wondering how to get the device GUID of a BLE node in windows 10.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, as I'm not familiar with the technical details of Bluetooth: If you tagged this question with [com] as in "communications port", please remove that tag and use [serial-port] instead. *You will get better answers*. The [com] tag is for the Microsoft Component Object Model, as in "Automation, Type Libraries, OLE, ActiveX, etc.". This question doesn't look like it belongs.

Comment: Actually I meant the component object model as the c++ api is based on com as per my understanding. I may be wrong but. There are not much examples available on this